# How to answer on Telegram inline query?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

My Telegram bot do not get answers to inline queries.

Here is some of the code that handles inline queries:

```
urlid = url['result'][0]['inline_query']['id']
            str(urlid)
            fromid = url['result'][0]['inline_query']['from']['id']
            str(fromid)
            query = url['result'][0]['inline_query']['query']
            if query == '/getinfo':  
                r = requests.get('http://' + address + ':' + port + '/')
                D = r.json() 
                message_text = str(len(D['info']))
                results = [{'type': 'article', 'message_text': message_text, 'id': '1', 'title': 'count'}]
                json.dumps(results)
                data = {'inline_query_id': urlid, 'results': results}
                bot.answerInlineQuery(data)
```

And this is answer function:

```
def answerInlineQuery(self, data):
        global url
        print('ok, we in answer func')
        sendurl = url + 'answerInlineQuery'
        requests.post(sendurl, data)
```

As you can see, there is a transition to function marker here: `print('ok, we in answer func')`. And when I enter an inline query, I see this message in the console. But the response to the request does not come to Telegram. This means that the request handler is working fine, but in the response function something wrong. Could you tell me what my mistake is?

UPD: I added `"input _message_content"` key to the `results` dict, but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `results` have little issue, it should be this format:

```
{"id": "1", "input _message_content": {"message_text": "Hello"}}
```

You can see official [reference](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequeryresultarticle) for more details.

Comment: You're right, I fixed it, but it does not work anyway.

Comment: I can't confirm this issue is about request body or your query. I think you should see Telegram error output for details.

Comment: Ok, I get this answer from server: Response [400].

Comment: No. I get it from console, I used for it this code in answer func: 

r = requests.post(sendurl, data) 
r.json()
print(r).

It's right?